# link_to div with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would i use

```
<% link_to (post) do %>
   <%= pluralize(post.comments.size,'comment') %>
<% end %>
```

to link to a div, for example the url:

```
http://myblog.com/post/21#mydiv
```

i need to do this so that when a user clicks the comments link they are taken to the comments div on the page. This would also be useful to use to redirect users to the comment they have just posted like so:

```
http://myblog.com/post/21#comment_id
```

thanks alot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
<% link_to(post, :anchor => 'mydiv') do %> 
   <%= pluralize(post.comments.size,'comment') %> 
<% end %>
```

- [link_to API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M002142)

Comment: it should start with <%=

Answer (score 2):

```
link_to(post, pluralize(post.comments.size,'comment'), :anchor => "mydiv")
```